# Using ComboBox Selections to Look though Multiple Columns on spreadsheet to match criteria and populate ListBox

Tags: vba, excel, lookup

Here is a visual of what I am trying to do

```
ConductorSize ComboBox Value = 1
ConductorClass ComboBox Value = C
```

```
CondSize    CondClass   CondStrand
 1000           B           61
 250            B           37
  1             B           19
  8             B           7
 1000           C           91
 250            C           61
  1             C           37
  8             C           19
```

I would like to be able to use the content the ComboBox Selections to match the values in Columns CondSize and CondClass and with this information, find the value that will match in Column CondStrand. CondStrand will be populated into a ListBox (CondStrand) in the same userform. So the listbox answer will be 37

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the below a look see...

I made an Example workbook and UserForm to test on Win7 and Excel 2007

I made a few assumptions:

```
1) Data is in Sheet1 code name Sheet1
2) Data is in Columns A, B, and C like your example
3) The Data has a Header in row 1 and Data starts on row 2
```

Place the below code into your UserForm module

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
' Delete this if you want to call the routine manually
    Call GetCondStrandValue
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
' Delete this if you want to call the routine manually
    Call GetCondStrandValue
End Sub

' To Manually call the routine
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call GetCondStrandValue_OnlyUniqueValues
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim RR As Range, rCell As Range
Dim objDictionary As Object
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With Sheet1
    Set RR = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .Clear
        For Each rCell In RR
            If Not objDictionary.Exists(rCell.Value) Then
                .AddItem rCell.Value
                objDictionary.Add rCell.Value, objDictionary.Count
            End If
        Next
    End With
    objDictionary.RemoveAll
    Set RR = .Range("B2:B" & .Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row)
    With Me.ComboBox2
        .Clear
        For Each rCell In RR
            If Not objDictionary.Exists(rCell.Value) Then
                .AddItem rCell.Value
                objDictionary.Add rCell.Value, objDictionary.Count
            End If
        Next
    End With
    objDictionary.RemoveAll
    Set objDictionary = Nothing
    With Me.ListBox1
        .Clear
    End With
End With
End Sub

Private Sub GetCondStrandValue()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim strValue As String

strValue = vbNullString
If Me.ComboBox1.Value = vbNullString Or Me.ComboBox2.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

With Sheet1
    For iRow = 2 To .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        If StrComp(.Cells(iRow, 1).Value, Me.ComboBox1.Value, 1) = 0 And _
         StrComp(.Cells(iRow, 2).Value, Me.ComboBox2.Value, 1) = 0 Then
            strValue = .Cells(iRow, 3).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End With

If strValue = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
With Me.ListBox1
    'If you only want a single value in the listbox un-comment the .clear line
    'Otherwise, values will continue to be added
    '.Clear
    .AddItem strValue
    .Value = strValue
    .SetFocus
End With
End Sub

Private Sub GetCondStrandValue_OnlyUniqueValues()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim strValue As String
Dim objDictionary As Object

strValue = vbNullString
If Me.ComboBox1.Value = vbNullString Or Me.ComboBox2.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

With Sheet1
    For iRow = 2 To .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        If StrComp(.Cells(iRow, 1).Value, Me.ComboBox1.Value, 1) = 0 And _
         StrComp(.Cells(iRow, 2).Value, Me.ComboBox2.Value, 1) = 0 Then
            strValue = .Cells(iRow, 3).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End With

If strValue = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Me.ListBox1
    For iRow = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Not IsNull(.List(iRow)) Then
            If Not objDictionary.Exists(.List(iRow)) Then
                objDictionary.Add .List(iRow), objDictionary.Count
            Else
                .RemoveItem iRow
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not objDictionary.Exists(strValue) Then
        .AddItem strValue
        .Value = strValue
        .SetFocus
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

The UserForm Initialize event will build the values of ComboBoxes 1 and 2 based on Columns A and B.  A Dictionary Object is created so that only unique values are added.

I use the Combox Change Event to trigger the GetCondStrandValue routine which will loop through each row looking for matches between ComboBox 1 and a cell value in column A and ComboBox 2 and the cell in Column B in the same row.  If a match is found then the value in Column C on the same row is added to a variable which is then added to the listbox...

I made two flavors of the routine, the other routine (called by a CommandButton in my example) will only list unique values in the listbox.

You will likely need to modify the code to suite your environment but this should provide a good starting point and some direction.

Please let me know if something isn't working or if I need to modify something.  Thanks :)

Comment: @PatrickChurchill Thank you!  Glad it helped.  Don't forget to accept the answer if it is what you where looking for.